# Weird packet lost. Looking for some input

Tags: multicast, latency, packet-loss

Like me start by saying I'm not an network expert but this situation got me scratching my head and you guys might be able to help.

The infrastructure is 4 switches (Dell 2848). 2 For the LAN and 2 for the DMZ (for redundancy. Different subnets). Each switch goes into the firewall (Watchguard) into their own NIC. (With link-aggregation).

This setup has been working fine for 2 years. Since last week we get intermittent high latency then loss of connection. This happens randomly and normally last less then a couple of minutes and come back on its own. We lose connection to both DMZ switches and all servers inside the said DMZ.

Here's what Nagios is reporting:

```
[09-25-2018 09:13:06] SERVICE ALERT: prd-server;Ping check;OK;SOFT;2;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.45 ms

Service Critical[09-25-2018 09:11:09] SERVICE ALERT: prd-server;Ping check;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;PING CRITICAL - Packet loss = 28%, RTA = 2206.04 ms

Service Critical[09-25-2018 09:10:52] SERVICE ALERT: prd-server;PHP Error Logs;CRITICAL;HARD;1;CRITICAL - Plugin timed out
```

The problem seems to only be touching both the DMZ switches and server located in the DMZ. The only thing that was changed was 3 days prior we enable Bridge Multicast Filtering and IGMP Snooping Status with Auto Learn.

Could it be a dying firewall that have trouble routing packets between the subnets ? Dying switch ? Multicast problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to include more information. For example, a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the (sanitized) network device configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance. We need to know more, or we can only speculate or guess, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Additionally, we'll need to see the logs from the switches - likely there's something wrong with STP, LACP or there's a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled Bridge Multicast Filtering and IGMP Snooping Status and everything went back to normal. Thanks all

Comment: And you think we should have guessed that from that scant info from you?